# import error while running a program in python the following error message occurred

Tags: python, windows

while running a program in python the following error message occurred.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Student\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python\cos.py",
> line 7, in 
> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   File "C:\Users\Student\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib_*init*_.py",
> line 174, in 
> *check_versions()   File "C:\Users\Student\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib_*init**.py",
> line 159, in _check_versions
> from . import ft2font ImportError: DLL load failed while importing ft2font: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please include your code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

This error message means that  (f2tfont.cpp does not compile)
First

```
pip uninstall matplotlib 
pip install -U matplotlib==3.2.0rc1
```

If this does not work out

You need to have Visual Studio c++ in Your System.

Install Visual Studio 2019 with c++ distributions .

i hope this will fix your error